# Angular and Node confusing variables

Tags: angularjs, node.js

My stack is: Angular 1.6.4 and Node v6.10.0. I use Node for the main routing of my site and Angular for the sub pages. I have multiple Angular apps for the same site due to some Angular limitations (out of scope for this issue).

My problem is - whenever I pass variables from an Angular controller, the site thinks it's coming from Node as they both have the same way to detect dynamic variables.

Code below:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.profileID = '12345678';
console.log('$scope.profileID is: ' + $scope.profileID);//This prints out just fine

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
  <script src="/jsLib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/angular/angularApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testController">
  <div>
    <p>{{profileID}}</p><!--This comes out as blank-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can use: $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');  and $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]'); to change the symbols but then, it breaks some 3rd party tools I am using which aren't written to support this.

Does anyone know of another way? Also, I never pass anything from Node to the frontend. It is there purely for the routing and API purposes so if I can stop this "passing" of variables from Node, that will do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how the site can "think" it comes from Node, as Node is server-side and Angular client-side, their codes never ever mix, so they can't conflict. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Both Angular and Node passes variables to the HTML with: {{ varName }}. So in this case, it is indeed confusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the below in the initial app.js app:

```
app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';
```

By the way, I was using the 'hogan-express' templating engine.

Hope this comes in handy to someone at some point. I was looking entirely in the wrong place.